# Date showing as serial number in formula

Tags: arrays, date, google-sheets, format, unique

I'm currently having an issue with the date format.
I have basically extracted the month and year from a standard dd/mm/yyyy date and wish this to be formatted as mmm yyyy ie Jan 2022 for use in a dropdown. This dropdown is then used to filter data using a query formula.

I have broken my sheet down to a 'test' sheet at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ITHMU_ad1LNKWff9q_mHLyb0SaISVyRYunYqA5-ndhU/edit?usp=sharing

You will see the issue I am having in the Dropdown Data Change sheet. The dropdown is in `A2` and although it shows the correct format in the dropdown list, in the formula bar it is actually showing as a dd/mm/yyyy format which is then showing as the serial number in the formula I have extracted into `D2` - this is then having a negative impact on my query formula in `A5` as it is querying against the Jan 2022 formatting.

I have tried the usual formatting options built into sheets as well as attempting to concatenate the data in the Haulage sheet where the data is input and the month and year are extracted but no use so far, so I turn to the experts please?

Comment: Dropdowns won't let you CHOOSE a date value that is formatted like mmm yyyy. YOu have to force the dropdown to display a TEXT value mmm yyyy.  Then, in your query() that uses the dropdown as an input, you force it BACK into a date value by multiplying it by 1.  See the new tab called MK_Help on your shared sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of your:

```
=Haulage!M7:M102)
```

use:

```
=INDEX(TO_TEXT(UNIQUE(Haulage!M7:M102)))
```

[image]